# TeamCity CheckMarx Plug-In : Reached maximum upload size limit of 200 MB

Tags: teamcity, devops, checkmarx

I have integrated CheckMarx plug-in on TeamCity as build step and trying to execute this build step under Commit step of the Project. However, its failing with below error:

```
    [Step 7/7] Unexpected exception: Reached maximum upload size limit of 200 MB
    [Step 7/7] java.io.IOException: Reached maximum upload size limit of 200 MB
at com.checkmarx.teamcity.agent.CxZip.zipWorkspaceFolder(CxZip.java:52)
at com.checkmarx.teamcity.agent.CxBuildProcess.zipWorkspaceFolder(CxBuildProcess.java:239)
at com.checkmarx.teamcity.agent.CxBuildProcess.createScan(CxBuildProcess.java:218)
at com.checkmarx.teamcity.agent.CxBuildProcess.call(CxBuildProcess.java:111)
at com.checkmarx.teamcity.agent.CxBuildProcess.call(CxBuildProcess.java:39)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    [Step 7/7] java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: jetbrains.buildServer.RunBuildException: java.io.IOException: Reached maximum upload size limit of 200 MB
```

Please suggest on how we can update (increase) the upload size limit?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

go to **Administration** -> **Global Settings**

Set **Maximum build artifact file size:** bigger

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I have already set this value to 300MB but it still fails with error showing "upload size limit as 200MB". 
Does it reserve some memory for other tasks?

Comment: do you have a free size on the disk where TC located the artefacts?

Comment: Yes, it does have.

Comment: Is it possible to restart TC ?

Comment: Should I restart TC build agent service or TC server after updating artifact file size?

Comment: TC server after updating artifact file size.

Answer (score 0):

The Checkmarx IIS server has a limit of 200 MB, so you would also need to change that.  One thing that also might be helpful is excluding directories/files that Checkmarx can't scan like any compiled code in the Checkmarx-TC step.

Comment: Could you please help me in knowing where exactly the settings are stored for CheckMarx IIS server? Is it on TeamCity server?